# What is better way to specify location of user : 3 columns or one location varchar column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some way to assign address to the user . Address consists of three values :

```
country
region 
city
```

It is possible to create 3 columns for country, region and city.
But it is also possible to create one varchar column and separate country,region,city by comma.

Which approach is better if I need to query for user by country and/or region and/or city?

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to store the address in 3 separate columns. This makes it easier to search by one value or using and/or statements to query based off of several values.

Comment: But I can use mysql LIKE keyword to search for specific country in varchar.

Comment: Think of New York, a state and a city, ... It's almost never a good idea to violate the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), if one's using a relational database. And that's atomicity. One single value in one field.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Also `LIKE` is only [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) when used without a leading %. So searching for regions and cities will be slower than if it's a separate field

Answer (score 0):

Another option to keep your main table small (and fast for processing): if you won't need the region and country all the time, create separate tables for each, then you can use a JOIN only when you need to determine these values (you'll join the city back to a country and a country back to a region - aka continent). This falls under the category of Data Normalization. Good luck.